# Make textarea required. Help

Tags: php, html

i cant make textarea purchase note required in woocomerce dokan
[image]

can i use purchase note for selling keys and soft? Its safely?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while. Give this a try. It's working on my free theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'your_override_checkout_fields' );

function your_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 $fields['order']['order_comments']['required'] = true;
 return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Where i need to paste this code? I talking about this https://ibb.co/Pgr1xxq

Comment: You could add this to your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: yes but i need to make purchase note required when you add product in dokan. Not when purchase. See screenshot ibb.co/Pgr1xxq